# Guardar datos en una base de datos desde un AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy intentando crear una app que guarde en una base de datos de SQLite unos datos cogidos de contactos de movil y luego guardarlos en una base de datos para hacer consultas posteriormente

```
  public void agenda(View v){
        datosAgenda();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Elige las personas que van al concierto");

for (int j = 0 ; j <= lista_contactos.size(); j++){
    ArrNumAgenda =  listaNumeros.toArray(new String[j]);
    ArrAgenda = lista_contactos.toArray(new String[j]);
}
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(ArrAgenda, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                for(int i = 0 ; i <= ArrAgenda.length ; i++){
                    if(i == (which)){

                        ArrAgendaAux.add(ArrAgenda[i]);

                        ArrNumAgendaAux.add(ArrNumAgenda[i]);


                    }
                }
            }
        });


        builder.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);


        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
    public void botonConfirmar(View v){
        System.out.println(concierto.getText().toString());
        System.out.println(fecha.getText().toString());

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO conciertos VALUES('"+concierto.getText().toString()+"','"+fecha.getText().toString()+"')");

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= ArrAgendaAux.size() ; i++){


        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO contactos VALUES('"+ ArrAgendaAux.get(i) +"','"+ArrNumAgendaAux.get(i)+"','"+concierto.getText().toString()+"','"+fecha.getText().toString()+"')");

    }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this , ActivityNuevoConcierto.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

El error me lo da en esta linea de codigo :

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO contactos VALUES('"+ ArrAgendaAux.get(i) +"','"+ArrNumAgendaAux.get(i)+"','"+concierto.getText().toString()+"','"+fecha.getText().toString()+"')");
```

Cuando he sacado por pantalla los datos en el alertDialog me los saca bien pero luego cuando intento meterlos en la base de datos me da el error

Este es el código , lo que intento hacer es guardar  todos lo datos cogidos del aletDialog mediante checkbox en una tabla de SQLite

Comment: que error te esta dando?, podrias colocarlo en la pregunta?

Comment: Me da un indexOutOfBounds pero no veo el error, Lo siento pero soy nuevo programando

Comment: Si tienes un IndexOutOfBounds exception, significa que estás accediendo a una posición del array que no existe.  Debuggea y comprueba el valor de which cuando insertas en la BBDD (+ArrAgenda[which])

Comment: Sospecho que tu problema esta en esta linea ArrAgenda = lista_contactos.toArray(new String[i]); podrias indicar cual es el tipo de dato de lista_contactos, asi puedo estar seguro de lo que esta pasando.

Answer (score 0):

Vale el error esta en for

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <= ArrAgendaAux.size() ; i++){
```

porque al recorrerlo tengo el <= por lo que si el size de la lista era 3 el for recorria hasta 4(contado el 0)

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < ArrAgendaAux.size() ; i++){
```

Con este for ya funciona